# Html content to PNG file

Tags: symfony

In php,Is it possible to convert the whole html content to IMAGE(PNG).I tried out with gd library the image is created but image shows white screen.Can any one help me to solve this issue.

Comment: You should post the code you are having a problem with.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend

```
  https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpSnappyBundle
```

as this can export html content to an image file.

great documentation can also provided